# Copy selected Excel range to Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, outlook

I want to copy the selected Excel Range "A1 to G5" from Sheet "PUCCH" to Outlook in vbs script.

I have the error

> Type mismatch

in line `.HTMLBody= "PUCCH:<br>" & objWorksheet.Range("A1:G5")`

```
Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set email = outlook.CreateItem(0)
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("X:\d\PCCW\realtime_MTR\PUCCH_level.XLSX")
Set xlSht = xlBook.Sheets("PUCCH")

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")                                                               
Set objWorkbook =objExcel.Workbooks.Open("X:\d\PCCW\realtime_MTR\PUCCH_level.XLSX")  

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("PUCCH") 
objWorksheet.Activate

With email
    '.to="Email;"
    .to="Email;"
    .Subject="Houly MTR Alerter"
    .HTMLBody= "PUCCH:<br>" & objWorksheet.Range("A1:G5")
    .Send
End With 
Wscript. quit
```

How can I correct the .HTMLBody in .Range()?

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to copy the range itself into the email, instead of reading out the values first and inserting these into your email. Depending on the format of these cells you could try something like this

```
Dim sRangeValues as String  
Dim r as Range

Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set email = outlook.CreateItem(0)
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("X:\d\PCCW\realtime_MTR\PUCCH_level.XLSX")
Set xlSht = xlBook.Sheets("PUCCH")

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")                                                               
Set objWorkbook =objExcel.Workbooks.Open("X:\d\PCCW\realtime_MTR\PUCCH_level.XLSX")  

Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("PUCCH") 
objWorksheet.Activate

set r = objWorksheet.Range("A1:G5")

For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To r.Rows(i).Columns.Count
        sRangeValues = sRangeValues & r.Rows(i).Columns(j).Value & "|"
    Next
    sRangeValues = sRangeValues & Chr(10)
Next

With email
       '.to="Email;"
       .to="Email;"
       .Subject="Houly MTR Alerter"
       .HTMLBody= "PUCCH:<br>" & sRangeValues
       .Send

End With 
Wscript. quit
```